# Is the output of a line integral over a scalar field a vector?

Tags: vectors, integration, vector-fields, mathematics

In my physics book of "mathematical methods for physics", the author writes that line integral of a scalar function $\phi$ over a curve $C$ can be written as the following:
$$\int_C\phi\,\text d{\textbf r}=\textbf{i}\int_C\phi(x,y,z)\,\text dx\,+\textbf{j}\int_C\phi(x,y,z)\,\text dy\,+\textbf{k}\int_C\phi(x,y,z)\,\text dz\,$$

Is it not supposed to be a numerical value? If we parametrize the curve $=()$ with $≤≤$ then evaluate $\int_a^(())|()|$ we get such a number, not a vector. $()$ is the derivative of $()$ wrt $$

I posted this on MSE too: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3479481/328520 but it was unhelpful.

It might come down to understanding the difference between $\int_C\phi\,\text d{\textbf r}$ and $\int_C\phi\,\text ds$. I have never seen a differential in the form of a vector in any of my calculus books.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You could treat this equation as the definition of the integral on the left.  For fun, think about what it would look like in spherical-polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, you can think of integrals as just a continuous, infinite sum. You are adding up elements of $\phi\,\text d\mathbf r$ along the specified path. $\phi$ is a scalar multiplying a vector quantity $\text d\mathbf r$. So you are essentially just adding up a bunch of vectors. Thus, your integral gives you a vector quantity.

Comment: This isn't a conventional line integral, though, right? I mean, I get that it's a valid mathematical object, but it doesn't seem to bear much resemblence to the thing we usually refer to as a line integral.

Comment: It has some resemblance; if you imagine that a vector field is then dotted with it, that could potentially commute into the line integral as the position coordinates are now living in different spaces, or, you can make them the same space if the vector field had a constant direction (with $\phi = \sqrt{v\cdot v} \phi'$). In that sense you could imagine that there is some relationship with some sort of mean field approximation, maybe.